# How to resolve the key not available error on deadsnakes ppa

Tags: ppa, repository

I keep getting the following error message everytime I sudo update.

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BA6932366A755776
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BA6932366A755776
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am unable to remove the deadsnakes ppa nor am I able to install any new packages. Could use some help with this.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the key.

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776`

Comment: Where did you get the alphanumeric string value after `recv-keys`? I see part of it in the question, but not all.

Comment: I literally googled for it. Search for `NO_PUBKEY BA6932366A755776` and you'll find an issue on the deadsnakes github issues. https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/53

Comment: The "alphanumeric string value" is the "fingerprint" of the "signing key" available from the deadsnakes repo front page: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa